# Why is the selectedCalendars property of EKCalendarChooser null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekeventkit

I have a `EKCalendarChoosere` which allows me to select calendars. I see the calendars and the delegate methods (`EKCalendarChooserDelegate`) get called. However when I access the selected calendars property of the calendar chooser they are always null. Does one need to manually add them or does the chooser handle that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you still are interested in why the **calendarChooserSelectionDidChange** method returns a NULL result for **selectedCalendars**. I was having the same issue.

When **calendarChooserSelectionDidChange** delegate method gets called, if the
**EKCalendarChooser** is setup using **EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleSingle** everything works perfectly.
But if it's setup for **EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple**, the **calendarChooserSelectionDidChange** delegate method fires, but the **calendarChooser.selectedCalendars** will return NULL, unless you set the NSSet of calendars for the EKCalendarChooser when setting it up i.e.: detailViewController.selectedCalendars = mySelectedCalendars; or detailViewController.selectedCalendars = [NSSet setWithArray:[eventStore calendars]];

Comment: I am having an issue in how you would implement this. Could you maybe include your code for the solution? I am desperate!!!!! haha

Comment: This is not right. It will precheck all the items in the set. If you don't want them selected, just use an empty set.

Answer (score 4):

Seems it is not necessary to populate the `NSSet`, just alloc-init it (in `EKCalendarChooser`'s `viewDidLoad`): [EKCalendarChooser multiple selection does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452845/ekcalendarchooser-multiple-selection-does-not-work/11975229#11975229)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you do what's suggested in the accepted answer, then all the items in the set are checked when the VC is presented.