# EKCalendarChooser multiple selection does not work

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uikit, eventkit

I'm trying to use `EKCalendarChooser` to get multiple calendars selected by the user. This is how I present the view:

```
EKCalendarChooser* dvc= [[[EKCalendarChooser alloc] initWithSelectionStyle:EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple displayStyle:EKCalendarChooserDisplayAllCalendars eventStore:eventStore] autorelease];

dvc.selectedCalendars= self.selectedCalendars;
dvc.delegate= self;
dvc.contentSizeForViewInPopover= CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);

self.popOver= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:dvc];
[self.popOver release];
self.popOver.delegate= self;

UIBarButtonItem* item= sender;

[self.popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:item permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

I get the `calendarChooserSelectionDidChange` message once I select one or more calendars, but every time the selectedCalendars property of the `EKCalendarChooser` is empty!

```
- (void)calendarChooserSelectionDidChange:(EKCalendarChooser *)calendarChooser
{
   NSLog(@"selected %d calendars", calendarChooser.selectedCalendars.count);
}

2012-02-26 12:50:39.137 MyApp[8604:707] selected 0 calendars
2012-02-26 12:50:42.100 MyApp[8604:707] selected 0 calendars
```

When I use `EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleSingle` instead of `EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple`, everything works fine and I will get the correct selected calendar through the selectedCalendars property.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is this a bug in `EKCalendarChooser`?

Answer (score 6):

If your `self.selectedCalendars` are nil you have to initialize the `dvc.selectedCalendars` with an valid but empty set.

```
dvc.selectedCalendars = [[NSSet alloc] init];
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I don't have to do this in single selection mode. Will try when at home though.

Comment: I did this, but it did help. I wasn't initializing the NSSet variable earlier. Either way, using the multiple selection feature still doesn't work for me. I output the selected calendars at the instance they are selected, but when selected, null null null 0 0 0 pops up everywhere, I am doing alot of checks to see where they data is but NOTHING is being referenced. I feel like apple just forgot to implement the EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple type or something. Because it clearly isn't returning any clicked cells.

Comment: 2015, still need to alloc init the `selectedCalendars` in order for the multiple selection style to work properly.